# Event not firing

Tags: c#

Can someone explain what is wrong with this code? This event will not fire when I make a call to mco.

```
    private ModiconComunications.ModiconComObject withEventsField_mco = new ModiconComunications.ModiconComObject();
    private ModiconComunications.ModiconComObject mco
    {
        get { return withEventsField_mco; }
        set
        {
            if (withEventsField_mco != null)
            {
                withEventsField_mco.GetDataReturn -= mco_GetDataReturn;
            }
            withEventsField_mco = value;
            if (withEventsField_mco != null)
            {
                withEventsField_mco.GetDataReturn += mco_GetDataReturn;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I call the below line, it should fire off the event mco_GetDataReturn, however, it does not. What have I done incorrectly?

```
    mco.GetData(ModiconComunications.ModiconComObject.GetDataType.READ_MODICON_HREGS, 11421, 9, 0);
```

Comment: i don't see any event firing code.

Comment: Are you able to confirm that the object is actually invoking the event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you initial withEventsField_mco, the one that is created by this line:

```
private ModiconComunications.ModiconComObject withEventsField_mco = new ModiconComunications.ModiconComObject();
```

Doesn't get it's event handlers hooked up. Unless you are doing that in the constructor.

Comment: Isn't that what the set statement is doing in the mco event?

Comment: @MarkoLombardi: Not unless you actually do `mco = withEventsField_mco` somewhere. You are bypassing the setter by setting `withEventsField_mco` directly and thus bypassing the code in the setter that hooks up the events.

Answer (score 1):

A little more code would be helpfull.

You init withEventsField_mco with a new object. 
However since you don't use the setter on the mco property no events get wired.

try this to test this reasonig:

```
McocontainingObject.mco = new ModiconComunications.ModiconComObject();
mco.GetData(ModiconComunications.ModiconComObject.GetDataType.READ_MODICON_HREGS, 11421, 9, 0);
```

or in your constructor

```
class McoContainer{
   private ModiconComunications.ModiconComObject withEventsField_mco;

   public McoContainer(){
      this.mco = new ModiconComunications.ModiconComObject();
   }

   public ModiconComunications.ModiconComObject mco{
      get{...}
      set{...}
   }
}
```